# Cannot start the Net-SNMP daemon from systemd (but it works from the command-line)

Tags: arch-linux, net-snmp, systemd

When I start Net-SNMP from systemd, there is no error message but the daemon does not run:

```
% sudo systemctl start snmpd
%
```

When I start it from the command line, it runs:

```
% sudo /usr/sbin/snmpd
```

and answers to SNMP queries.

If I add the debug flags (-LSdd), I see that the daemon launched by systemd is killed immediately after:

```
Apr  7 15:37:50 localhost snmpd[1298]: NET-SNMP version 5.7.2
Apr  7 15:37:50 localhost snmpd[1298]: Received TERM or STOP signal...  shutting down...
```

The service file is the default one of the Arch Linux package:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd 
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I add RemainAfterExit=yes in the service file, snmpd works but the machine no longer starts properly (no DHCP client, for instance)

The system is an up-to-date Arch Linux, the version of the package is:

```
Name           : net-snmp
Version        : 5.7.2-3
```

There is an old Arch Linux bug report apparently for this very bug: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32258?string=snmp&project=1&type%5B0%5D=&sev%5B0%5D=&pri%5B0%5D=&due%5B0%5D=&reported%5B0%5D=&cat%5B0%5D=&status%5B0%5D=open&percent%5B0%5D=&opened=&dev=&closed=&duedatefrom=&duedateto=&changedfrom=&changedto=&openedfrom=&openedto=&closedfrom=&closedto=

Comment: This service file apparently works fine: https://github.com/CleverCloud/CleverCloud-exheres/blob/master/packages/net/net-snmp/files/systemd/snmpd.service Now, I would appreciate explanations about why it works and why the default one does not :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the fork of snmpd during start.

My service file (for Exherbo) forces snmpd to not use `fork()` (`-f`) and run the service with `Type=simple`.

`Type=forking` is the good way for the default behavior of snmpd, but it is incomplete.

It is highly recommended to specify `PIDFile` when using `Type=forking` because systemd is not always able to know which process to monitor after the first process exits.

Just add this:

```
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/snmpd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -p /var/run/snmpd.pid
```

This change will also fix `ExecReload`.